# css on blog dynamic view

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I want to change some values of my CSS depending on the blog type. For doing that I scan all
`document.styleSheets` and try to read `document.styleSheets[i].cssRules`.

But for my linked inside `<head>` tags CSS's (for instance `<link href='https://olga4-romleon.c9users.io/ini/iniView.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>` ) - the cssRules's are `null`. They are `NULL` but in the meantime they are working!

Could anybody answer my questions:

- how can I read/change rules for loaded-linked CSS?
- where are kept/stored all loaded-linked  CSS (how to see them in my blog) as they are not presented in cssRules?

Thanks